# Upload XML payload into multiple Exact Online companies

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

Using a query as below, you get output in the XML format required for Exact Online.

These XML messages can be put in many files on disk using:

```
local export documents in filecontents to "c:\temp\in" filename column filename
```

And then loaded into Exact Online's current division using:

```
local eol batch import xml "Accounts" in "c:\temp\in\Accounts" success "c:\temp\success" fail "c:\temp\fail"
```

This works fine for one division, but not when you load 100 divisions/companies.

How can I directly load data from the SQL into multiple companies/divisions at the same time instead of using an individual `local eol batch import xml` statement and `use DIVISIONCODE` statement?

Query sample:

```
select 'Accounts\010-Accounts.xml' 
       filename
,      stg.fileprefix 
       || chr(13)
       || '<Accounts>' 
       || xml 
       || chr(13)
       || '</Accounts>'
       || stg.filepostfix
       filecontents
from   ( select listagg
                ( chr(13)
                  || '<Account code="'
                  || xmlencode(custsupid)
                  || '" status="'
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload into multiple companies/divisions with one statement using the following syntax as described on [UploadXMLTopics](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinexml-xml-uploadxmltopics.html):

```
insert into UploadXMLTopics@eol
( topic
, payload
, division_code
)
select topic
,      filecontents
,      division_code
from   ...
```

Even when one or more of the uploads fail, the insert will not report an error and process all XML messages.

You can see the results afterwards using:

```
select *
from   UploadXMLTopics
```

The column `SUCCESSFUL` indicates whether the payload column was loaded succesfully.

In `RESULT` column you will find the return message of Exact Online, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-XML.xsd">
    <Messages>
        <Message type="0">
            <Topic code="FinYears" node="FinYear" />
            <Date>2016-12-09T09:02:36</Date>
            <Description>Kan boekjaar niet aanmaken: 2014 vanwege ontbrekende boekjaren. Het laagste boekjaar in Exact Online is 2016.</Description>
        </Message>
        <Message type="2">
            <Topic code="FinYears" node="FinYear">
                <Data key="2015" keyAlt="2015" />
            </Topic>
            <Date>2016-12-09T09:02:37</Date>
            <Description>Aangemaakt</Description>
        </Message>
    </Messages>
</eExact>
```